# Does Selenium IDE uses Selenium to control the browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Or it just does it through Javascript?

This is because I have some steps in wd.js that I'd want to be able to execute it as custom commands. But I think I can only really do that if Selenium IDE uses Selenium... if it uses Javascript to control the browser, then probably is impossible, because wd.js uses Selenium to work.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium IDE does record Selenium scripts sometimes with native methods, such as `.click()`  and  `.navigate().to(url)/.go(url)`, as far as I know.   So, when you re-run the script, it will call native browser events, and not necessarily all 100% non-native Javascript events, such as `.findElement(By)`.   NOTE: I prefer Selenium Builder over Selenium IDE.

Comment: When Selenium IDE re-run the script, it calls to Selenium? Or has Selenium integrated with Selenium IDE? I'm wondering if this Selenium could be called from outside as normal Selenium can be called. No luck trying to find it with ps and other process listing commands.

Comment: Yes, the recordings are compatible with regular Selenium, although you need to tweak the scripts to get it working in your test runner.  I prototyped something like that once, long ago:  https://github.com/djangofan/simple-selenium-builder-framework